# quotes in onclick event

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I had an onclick event as below.

```
<div onclick="display_function('<?php echo $user_id;?>','<?php echo $student_id;?>','<?php echo $student_name;?>')"></div>


function display_function(user_id,student_id,student_name)
{
   alert(user_id+'-'+student_id+'-'+student_name); //<-- testing only. I have my own code here
}
```

the function works fine with the name like Mary, Chris and etc.

However, if the student name contains a `'`, e.g. `Cheng'li`, the function won't work.

I need help to fix this. How can I make the function works by 'escaping' the quote mark in name?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add a call to [`htmlentities`](http://php.net/htmlentities) around the data you wish to echo.
Not doing so exposes your code to XSS attacks.

Answer (score 1):

use PHP function addslashes

```
<?php
$str = "Is your name O'reilly?";

// Outputs: Is your name O\'reilly?
echo addslashes($str);
?>
```

IN your case

```
<?php echo addslashes($student_name);?>
```

REFERENCE

http://www.php.net/addslashes

Note: If your code contain html tag than use htmlentities (Entoarox Answer)

Comment: `htmlentities()` is better for this case, as in Entoarax's answer.

Comment: @Barmar i think student_name is not going to contain html related stuff,it simply be string with quotes

Comment: What about HTML tags?

Comment: if it's provided by the user, you can't be sure of what it might contain. http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: @rajeshkakawat Unless another area of his code cleans that bit of data, it could contain html, and thus should use htmlentities to protect against it (Just because something should not happen, doesnt mean it wont)

Answer (score 0):

you can either use `escape()`

```
<div onclick="display_function(escape('<?php echo $user_id;?>'),escape('<?php echo $student_id;?>'),escape('<?php echo $student_name;?>'))"></div>


function display_function(user_id,student_id,student_name)
{
   alert(user_id+'-'+student_id+'-'+student_name); //<-- testing only. I have my own code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because you are passing the values in function in single quotes. When name will have a single quote, this will cause error.

try double quotes like

```
<div onclick="display_function(\"<?php echo $user_id;?>\",\"<?php echo $student_id;?>\",\"<?php echo $student_name;?>\")"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Just add \ before ' to tell your script that it is a string. I hope it helps

```
<?php 
    $user_id = 1;
    $student_id = 1;
    $student_name = "Cheng\'li";
?>

<div onclick="display_function('<?php echo $user_id;?>','<?php echo $student_id;?>','<?php echo $student_name;?>')">Click</div>

<script>
function display_function(user_id,student_id,student_name)
{
   alert(user_id+'-'+student_id+'-'+student_name); //<-- testing only. I have my own code here
}
</script>
```

If you cannot put \ directly in String, you need to use `[addslashes][1]`

```
<script>
    function display_function(user_id,student_id,student_name)
    {
       alert(user_id+'-'+student_id+'-'+addslashes(student_name)); //<-- testing only. I have my own code here
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: He's getting the value from a database, not a literal.

Comment: Thank you Barmar. I have edited my answer. I think it will be better